# Where did "Speed Factor" go? (Video Sequencer)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

[image]

In version 4.0.2 there is no "Speed Factor" option. Where does this option live now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system has changed since Blender 4, you need to select the strip, enable *Show Retiming Keys* option and move the keys to speed up or slow down, it will be displayed in percentage. It looks a bit buggy for the moment, you may need to change the strip track to see the last key (??):

[image]

If you want to add a key go into *Strip > Retiming > Add Retiming Key*. And to set speed manually, *Strip > Retiming > Set Speed*:

[image]